# How do I shade a cone to match ball shading?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

How do I shade a cone like this
[image: shaded cone]

Note that the bright part is wider at the bottom (because the radius is greater there).
The intent is that the cone and `\tikz \shadedraw[ball color=red] circle[radius=1];` if placed next to one another should look like they are illuminated by the same (infinitely distant) light source.

I drew the cone above by faking the shading:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
       \begin{scope}
          \draw[clip] ({-sqrt(91)/10},9/100) coordinate (A) 
             arc[x radius=1, y radius=0.3, start angle=180-17.46, end angle=360+17.46]
             -- (0,1) -- cycle;
          \fill[red] (0,1) -- (-1.3628,-0.3) -- (1.3628,-0.3) -- cycle;
          \foreach \i in {0,1,...,100} {
             \fill[white!\i!red] (0,1) -- (-1.3628+\i*0.006814,-0.3) -- +(0.008,0) -- cycle;
             \fill[red!\i!white] (0,1) -- (-0.6814+\i*0.006814,-0.3) -- +(0.008,0) -- cycle;
             \fill[red!\i!black!50!red] (0,1) -- (0.6814-\i*0.006814,-0.3) -- +(-0.008,0) -- cycle;
             \fill[black!\i!red!50!black] (0,1) -- (0.6814+\i*0.006814,-0.3) -- +(-0.008,0) -- cycle;
          }
          \draw[dotted] (A) arc[x radius=1, y radius=0.3, start angle=180-17.46, end angle=17.46];
       \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

I have searched this forum and ctan without finding this style of shading.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Looks like a variant of `color wheel`.

Comment: Actually, I think your approach is really good and hardly to be improved. The ball shading is also nothing else than a radial gradient whose center is shifted a bit.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer. I copy this code from manual of [3DToolsManual.tex](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools/blob/master/3DToolsManual.tex)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}    
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view=%
    {phi=110,psi=0,theta=60}]
    \pic{3d/shaded cone={r=2,h=3}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]